# ocaml menhir parser production is never reduced

Tags: parsing, ocaml, menhir

I'm in the middle of learning how to parse simple programs.

This is my lexer.

```
{
open Parser
  exception SyntaxError of string
}

let white = [' ' '\t']+

let blank = ' '


let identifier = ['a'-'z']


rule token = parse
  | white {token lexbuf} (* skip whitespace *)
  | '-' { HYPHEN }
  | identifier {
    let buf = Buffer.create 64 in
    Buffer.add_string buf (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf);
    scan_string buf lexbuf;
    let content = (Buffer.contents  buf) in
    STRING(content)
  }
  | _ { raise (SyntaxError "Unknown stuff here") }

and scan_string buf = parse
  | ['a'-'z']+ {
    Buffer.add_string buf (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf);
    scan_string buf lexbuf
  }
  | eof { () }
```

My "ast":

```
type t =
    String of string
  | Array of t list
```

My parser:

```
%token <string> STRING
%token HYPHEN

%start <Ast.t> yaml
%%

yaml:
  | scalar { $1 }
  | sequence {$1} 
  ;

sequence:
  | sequence_items {
    Ast.Array (List.rev $1)
  }
  ;

sequence_items:
   (* empty *) { [] }
  | sequence_items HYPHEN scalar {
    $3::$1

  };

scalar:
  | STRING { Ast.String $1 }  
  ;
```

I'm currently at a point where I want to either parse plain 'strings', i.e.
`some text` or 'arrays' of 'strings', i.e. `- item1 - item2`.

When I compile the parser with Menhir I get:

```
Warning: production sequence -> sequence_items is never reduced.
Warning: in total, 1 productions are never reduced.
```

I'm pretty new to parsing. Why is this never reduced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declare that your entry point to the parser is called `main`

```
%start <Ast.t> main
```

But I can't see the `main` production in your code. Maybe the entry point is supposed to be `yaml`? If that is changed—does the error still persists?

---

Also, try adding `EOF` token to your lexer and to entry-level production, like this:

```
parse_yaml: yaml EOF { $1 }
```

See here for example: https://github.com/Virum/compiler/blob/28e807b842bab5dcf11460c8193dd5b16674951f/grammar.mly#L56

The link to Real World OCaml below also discusses how to use EOL—I think this will solve your problem.

---

By the way, really cool  that you are writing a YAML parser in OCaml. If made open-source it will be really useful to the community. Note that YAML is indentation-sensitive, so to parse it with Menhir you will need to produce some kind of `INDENT` and `DEDENT` tokens by your lexer. Also, YAML is a strict superset of JSON, that means it might (or might not) make sense to start with a JSON subset and then expand it. Real World OCaml shows how to write a JSON parser using Menhir:

https://dev.realworldocaml.org/16-parsing-with-ocamllex-and-menhir.html

Comment: I renamed `yaml` to `main`, because this is the very beginning of yaml parser and I'm already struggling with the very basics. :D
The reduce problem originates from the `yaml` variant.
I'll try and study realworldocaml.

Comment: Thanks it was indeed the EOF that did it!

Comment: Years later and I got caught by the EOF problem... Thanks for the clarification!